# __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to open the view for my posts but I keep getting the error '**str** returned non-string (type bytes)'. I read thhat I should use force_bytes and then unicode but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I fix it?

This is the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   """ Post
   """
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)
   body = models.TextField('Body')
   reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'),  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')

   def __str__(self):
       return force_bytes('%s' % self.title)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % self.title
```

Comment: Your `force_bytes` likely converts this to a `bytes` object.

Comment: just return `self.title` ....

Comment: If the code matches the advice (with the string change) - it may mean your python 2.7 files are cached. Delete all cache files after you've made the change -

Comment: @Glycerine I deleted the files but I still get the same error

Comment: @Glycerine Oh, it took some time but now it works so it must have been that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I read that I should use force_bytes and then unicode

I'm thinking the article you read may have been inaccurate - or perhaps referencing an older style of *unicode care*.

The `__str__` method should return a `string` type. As your `title` is already a string, this should work a treat:

```
def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

Comment: They're probably reading a guide for Python 2 development. In Python 3, there's no such thing as `__unicode__`; `__str__` does the same job `__unicode__` used to do, because `str` now handles arbitrary Unicode, not just bytes that are assumed to be ASCII.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I did try that and it returns the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method needs to return a `str`ing, not a `bytes` object. You thus can return the value of `self.title`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

That being said, it looks like you are still using [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x). This is no longer supported since January 2020, so it might be better to start working with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), and upgrade the Django version accordingly.

Comment: If they were on Python 2, `str` would *be* `bytes`. The `str`/`force_bytes` thing is unnecessary and wrong - it'll return something like `"b'...'"`. `return self.title` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This still returns the same error, though...

Comment: @satoru: are you sure that the this is the class that raises the error? Can you edit the question and share the *full* traceback?

Answer (score -2):

Try assigning the force byte to a variable and use .encode()
Method on it, and try returning... Hope this one helps.

Comment: encode is for strings, decode for bytes, so encoding the results of force_bytes don't work. Even if you would use decode(), it would be the equivalent of having an English sentence, translating it to Chinese and then back to English and returning that.